# file not found error in sring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
I am trying to run Spring MVC application which handles a simple user details save functionality from jsp to database and displaying the records on screen.

Technology stack used
OPEN JDK 8(Amazon Corretto)
Websphere Liberty Server 20.0
eclipse Oxygen

When I am trying to execute the code it is displaying index.jsp but from index.jsp. I have 2 links in index.jsp add user and list user when user clicks on adduser or list user it is throwing "JSPG0036E: failed to find the resourcejsp" error.

Can anyone please help.
Herewith attached the code block...

userController.java // ControllerClass
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.demo.bean.UserBean;
import com.demo.model.User;
import com.demo.service.UserService;
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/hello")
public class UserController {

 @Autowired
 private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute("command")UserBean userBean, 
   BindingResult result) {
  User user = prepareModel(userBean);
  userService.addUser(userBean);
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:/add.html");
 }

 @RequestMapping(value="/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView listUsers() {
  Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  model.put("users",  prepareListofBean(userService.listUsers()));
  return new ModelAndView("userList", model);
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView addUser(@ModelAttribute("command")UserBean userBean,
   BindingResult result) {
  Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  model.put("Users",  prepareListofBean(userService.listUsers()));
  return new ModelAndView("addUser", model);
 }

@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView welcome() {
  return new ModelAndView("index");
 }

@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editUser(@ModelAttribute("command")UserBean userBean,
   BindingResult result) {
  userService.deleteUser(prepareModel(userBean));
  Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  model.put("user", null);
  model.put("users",  prepareListofBean(userService.listUsers()));
  return new ModelAndView("addUser", model);
 }

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteUser(@ModelAttribute("command")UserBean userBean,
   BindingResult result) {
  Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  model.put("user", prepareUserBean(userService.getUser(userBean.getId())));
  model.put("users",  prepareListofBean(userService.listUsers()));
  return new ModelAndView("addUser", model);
 }

 private User prepareModel(UserBean userBean){
  User user = new User();
  user.setUserId(userBean.getUserId());
  user.setUserName(userBean.getUserName());
  user.setUserEmail(userBean.getUserEmail());
  return user;
 }

 private List<UserBean> prepareListofBean(List<User> user){
  List<UserBean> beans = null;
  if(user != null && !user.isEmpty()){
   beans = new ArrayList<UserBean>();
   UserBean bean = null;
   for(User user1 : user){
    bean = new UserBean ();
    bean.setUserId(user.getUserId());
    bean.setUserName(user.getUserName());
    bean.setUserEmail(user.getUserEmail());
   beans.add(bean);
   }
  }
  return beans;
 }

 private UserBean prepareUserBean(User user){
  UserBean  bean = new UserBean();
  bean.setUserId(user.getUserId());
  bean.setUserName(user.getUserName());
  bean.setUserEmail(user.getUserEmail());
  return bean;
 }
}

Index.jsp // Jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Spring3MVC with Hibernate3 CRUD Example using Annotations</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Spring3MVC with Hibernate3 CRUD Example using Annotations</h2>
    <h2>1. <a href="users.html">List of Users</a></h2>
    <h2>2. <a href="add.html">Add User</a></h2>
  </body>
</html>

AddUser.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Add User Data</h2>
  <form:form method="POST" action="/sdnext/add.html">
      <table>
       <tr>
           <td><form:label path="id">User ID:</form:label></td>
           <td><form:input path="id" value="${user.userId}" readonly="true"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><form:label path="name">User Name:</form:label></td>
           <td><form:input path="name" value="${user.userName}"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><form:label path="age">User eMail:</form:label></td>
           <td><form:input path="age" value="${user.userEmail}"/></td>
       </tr>
          <tr>
         <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>
   </table> 
  </form:form>

  <c:if test="${!empty users}">
  <h2>List Users</h2>
 <table align="left" border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>User ID</th>
   <th>User Name</th>
   <th>User Email</th>
    <th>Actions on Row</th>
  </tr>
  <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
   <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${user.userId}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.userName}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.userEmail}"/></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="edit.html?id=${user.userId}">Edit</a> | <a href="delete.html?id=${user.userId}">Delete</a></td>
   </tr>
  </c:forEach>
 </table>
</c:if>
 </body>
</html>
```

userController.java is my controller class. For me index.jsp executes successfully but when I click on add user it shows "File not found error" the mentioned error.I am using Apache ANT 1.9.9 as a build tool.
Code is getting build successfully but gives error in while executing Jsplink mentioned in index.jsp.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a bit of your code? The controller and the jsp-file would be helpful.

Comment: Sure, Please find the attached code block.

Answer (score 0):

You are Using `@RequestMapping` on class level so, now `/hello/` will be added to each maping for this class.
In    `<a>` tag 
Replace `href="add.html"` with 
    `href="/hello/add"`
Please do not use **.html** in link tag. i.e `<a>` or `action=someurl`  in `<form>` tag. 
The `<form action="/hello/add.html">` should be replace is with 
`action="/hello/add`" you don't need to pass the extension. This URL will be mapped with the controller not the page or file directly,  Then the controller with `@RequestMapping(value="/hello/")` will be executed then `@RequestMapping(value="add")` and final will become `/hello/add`

Please Do check file name and passed view name in `ModelAndView` would be same, **case sensitive** And please make sure your web.xml is configured properly.

Comment: Thank You Rajeev after applying all the changes it is still giving the same "Error 404: javax.servlet.ServletExeception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E:FileNotFound :/add" exception on execution .

Comment: Okay i missed one thing here, you are using @RequestMapping on Class also so it will be added in url to now your link will be /hello/add try this it will work.